# windows phone emulator problems

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wanted to start programming on windows phone.
So i installed windows phone sdk 7.1 with update (7.1.1).
I built an "hello world" program and wanted to start the program by running the emulator.
But, every time that i run the program on the emulator it stop:

[image]

I have:

-Windows 8.

-visual studio 2010.

-sdk 7.1.1

-core 2 duo

-RAM:4 GB.

What can be the problem that it stop before it begin?

Comment: Have you tried booting the emulator up beforehand in compatibility with W7? I only tried using the WP7 emulator in W8 once, and I got a BSOD, so I think there's some kind of compatibility issues somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not use Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Phone SDK 8? I think in Windows Phone Emulator run in VM so may be this problem is due to internet connection.

Comment: My computer can not run sdk 8 due to sdk 8 requirementsץ